# Binary Search Tree Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-search-tree

I have an insert function for a Binary Search Tree in Haskel. My insert functions first two lines look like this

```
insert :: (Ord a) => BST a -> a -> BST a
insert Nil x = Node x Nil Nil
```

I know the function works, I have tested it on single numbers. But now I am trying to apply the insert to a list. I tried this code

```
let mBST = foldr insert Nil [1,2,7,9,3,5]
```

and I get the following error

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = BST a0
Expected type: BST (BST a0) -> BST a0 -> BST a0
Actual type: BST (BST a0) -> BST a0 -> BST (BST a0)
In the first argument of `foldr', namely `insert'
In the expression: foldr insert Nil [1, 2, 7, 9, ....]
```

I there is an error in the BST a -> a -> BST a but I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foldr` has type `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`, which means it expects a function of type `a -> b -> b` as its first argument. In your particular example, that translates to `Integer -> BST Integer -> BST Integer`, which is different than insert's type.

The easiest solution would be to flip the insert function:

```
let mBST = foldr (flip insert) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that `foldr f init lst` passes `f` an element of the list and the result of folding up the rest of the list *in that order*. You can either write

```
insert :: (Ord a) => a -> BST a -> BST a
insert x Nil = Node x Nil Nil
```

(which would be more idiomatic) or write `foldr (flip insert) Nil`.

As you will probably learn soon, it's more efficient in cases like this to use a strict left fold instead of a right fold. Using your implementation, this is `foldl' insert Nil`. Using my (more idiomatic) one, this is `foldl' (flip insert) Nil`.